# Python Conditional Operator Useage

Tags: python, python-requests, conditional-operator

I'm trying to better understand a way to implement a conditional variable into a python requests' http request.

I'm doing the following:

```
def make_post(parameter1_value, parameter2='None'):

    payload = {
        "parameter1": parameter1_value,
        "parameter2": "None"
    }

    r = requests.post('https://myrequesturl.com/location/', params=payload)
```

I'm trying to find the best way to NOT include the `"parameter2": "None"` value in the params unless the value is not equal to `None`.

I realize I could have several conditional statements to select a proper format of request depending on the parameters, but then it would become sticky to scale for each additional `parameterN` needed in the function.

I'm wondering if there is a way to include a conditional type of variable in the `payload` that would have the effect of including that parameter only if it isn't equal to the default value set; in this case 'None'.

So if the the value of `parameter2` = `None`:

```
    payload = {
        "parameter1": parameter1_value
    }
```

But if the value of `parameter2` = anything other than `None`

```
payload = {
            "parameter1": parameter1_value,
            "parameter2": "Non_default_value"
        }
```

I'm trying to avoid the following type of approach:

```
if some_parameter != 'None':
    payload = {
                "one": "arrangement"
            }

if some_some_other_parameter != 'None':
    payload = {
                "one": "arrangement"
            }
```

It seems a bit impractical in an example of only two parameters, but if I were to have a function with many parameters it would seem that a one line include/exclude type expression would greatly reduce the amount of overall code required. It's been my experience when I can't figure out how to get python to do something clever it's only because I don't know how, and not that python can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def foo(v1, v2=None):
    params = {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if v!=None}
    print params

foo('hello')
foo('hello', 'world')
```

Output:

```
{'v1': 'hello'}
{'v1': 'hello', 'v2': 'world'}
```

---

Or

Something like this?

```
def foo(a={}, url=''):
    params = {k:v for k,v in a.items() if v!=None}
    print params

foo({'k1':'v1','k2':2,'k3':None, 'k4':'v4'})
foo()
```

Output:

```
{'k2': 2, 'k1': 'v1', 'k4': 'v4'}
{}
```

Comment: Great stuff! Really simple and does exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you so much.

Comment: for flexibility, I found that the following implementation of this worked best for my particular needs:    `def foo(token, **params):
    filtered_params = {k:v for k,v in locals().get('params').items() if v != token}
    ` —just as an added example for others.

Comment: @Frank Nice. You can do `params.items()` also instead of `locals().get('params').items()`.  The default variable name in Python is `*args` and `**kwargs` for positional and keyword arguments. When nothing is passsed `args = ()` and `kwargs = {}`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the follow up—that's considerably more elegant in IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would work for you, especially if the default values are specific to the key:

```
def optional_include_mut(payload, key, value, default=None):
    """
    Mutate the given payload dict by adding the given key/value pair if the value is not equal to default.

    :param payload: Dict to mutate
    :param key: Key to insert into dict
    :param value: Value to insert into dict
    :param default: Default value to control insertion
    :return: A mutated version of the payload dict
    """
    if value != default:
        payload[key] = value
    return payload

>>> payload = dict(good=1)
>>> payload = optional_include_mut(payload, 'foo', 'bar', default='bar')
{'good': 1}
>>> payload = optional_include_mut(payload, 'foo', 'bar', default='not bar')
{'good': 1, 'foo': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary comprehension to filter the values:

```
>>> payload = dict(a='value1',b='value2',c='None',d='None',e='value3')
>>> payload
{'a': 'value1', 'b': 'value2', 'c': 'None', 'd': 'None', 'e': 'value3'}
>>> {k:v for k,v in payload.items() if v != 'None'}
{'a': 'value1', 'b': 'value2', 'e': 'value3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this

```
>>> def fun(*param):
        return {"parameter{}".format(k): v for k,v in enumerate(param,1) if v not in (None,"None")}

>>> fun("hello","None","world",None,42)
{'parameter1': 'hello', 'parameter5': 42, 'parameter3': 'world'}
>>>
```

(`*param` is the way to said you want a variable numbers of arguments)

this way you can pass as many parameter as you want, and filter those with invalid values

with python 3 syntax you can also do it as

```
def fun(*param, invalid=(None,"None")):
    return {"parameter{}".format(k): v for k,v in enumerate(param,1) if v not in invalid}
```

for python 2 to accomplished the same would be

```
def fun(*param, **karg):
    invalid = karg.get("invalid", (None,"None") )
    return {"parameter{}".format(k): v for k,v in enumerate(param,1) if v not in invalid}
```

another example

```
>>> fun("hello","None","world",None,42,32, invalid=("None",None,32))
{'parameter1': 'hello', 'parameter5': 42, 'parameter3': 'world'}
>>>
```